# Falling to store current user in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, parse-platform

Something really strange is happening with my code and I don't know how to fix it.
When I want to store some users in core data it works but when I want to store my current user, it doesn't work, apparently the data I try to save is nil but when I print this same data to the log, everything seems perfectly fine

In a for loop I loop over all the users I want to store and if the username equals the one of the current user than I store the current user, otherwise I store the other users.

It is really weird because normally both operations, adding current user or adding other users, are the same.

My code:

```
    var managedObjectContext = AppDelegate().managedObjectContext

// MARK - Adding all the users in Core data
for userFromParseDataBase in usersFromParseDataBase {

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
    let newUser = Users(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)

    // Checking if the current user is correctly logged in
    if userFromParseDataBase.username == userName {

        print(userFromParseDataBase.username)
        print(userFromParseDataBase.profileName)

        // Adding other users interacting with currentUser
        newUser.username = userFromParseDataBase.username
        print(newUser.username)
        newUser.profileName = userFromParseDataBase.profileName
        let imageData = try! userFromParseDataBase.profileImage.getData()
        if (imageData.length != 0){
            newUser.photo = imageData
        }
        newUser.currentUser = true
        newUser.added = false

        do {
            try newUser.managedObjectContext?.save()
            self.usersFromCoreData.append(newUser)
            print("TEST 1 - current user has been saved to core data")
        } catch {
            let saveError = error as NSError
            print("ERROR CURRENT USERS : \(saveError), \(saveError.userInfo)")
        }

        // Checking if there are added users
    }else if self.arrayAddedUsers.contains(userFromParseDataBase.username) {

        // Adding added users
        newUser.username = userFromParseDataBase.username
        newUser.profileName = userFromParseDataBase.profileName
        let imageData = try! userFromParseDataBase.profileImage.getData()
        if (imageData.length != 0){
            newUser.photo = imageData
        }
        newUser.currentUser = false
        newUser.added = true
        do {
            try newUser.managedObjectContext?.save()
            self.usersFromCoreData.append(newUser)
            print("TEST 1 - added user has been saved to core data")
        } catch {
            let saveError = error as NSError
            print("ERROR ADDED USERS :\(saveError), \(saveError.userInfo)")
        }

        // Checking if the current user interacts with users that have not been added
    }else if self.arrayGroupMembers3.contains(userFromParseDataBase.username){

        print(userFromParseDataBase.username)
        print(userFromParseDataBase.profileName)

        // Adding other users interacting with currentUser
        newUser.username = userFromParseDataBase.username
        print(newUser.username)
        newUser.profileName = userFromParseDataBase.profileName
        let imageData = try! userFromParseDataBase.profileImage.getData()
        if (imageData.length != 0){
            newUser.photo = imageData
        }
        newUser.currentUser = false
        newUser.added = false

        do {
            try newUser.managedObjectContext?.save()
            self.usersFromCoreData.append(newUser)
            print("TEST 3 - interacting user has been saved to core data")
        } catch {
            let saveError = error as NSError
            print("ERROR INTERACTING USERS : \(saveError), \(saveError.userInfo)")
        }
    }else {
        print("No condition is true")
    }

}
```

This is what gets printed to the log, I print everything because it is important to see that the data I am passing is not supposed to be nil:

```
antoine@info.com
antoine
Optional("antoine@info.com")
TEST 2 - interacting user has been saved to core data
thomas@info.com
thomas
Optional("thomas@info.com")
ERROR CURRENT USERS : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1560 "(null)" UserInfo={NSDetailedErrors=(
"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)\" UserInfo={NSValidationErrorKey=profileName, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.), NSValidationErrorObject=<WeGrupp.Users: 0x7fd4d0c3fe60> (entity: Users; id: 0x7fd4d0c13310 <x-coredata:///Users/t9279CD60-1946-485B-BE68-F1EE10D8ACFE4> ; data: {\n    added = 0;\n    currentUser = 0;\n    groups =     (\n    );\n    photo = nil;\n    profileName = nil;\n    username = nil;\n})}",
"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)\" UserInfo={NSValidationErrorKey=username, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.), NSValidationErrorObject=<WeGrupp.Users: 0x7fd4d0c3fe60> (entity: Users; id: 0x7fd4d0c13310 <x-coredata:///Users/t9279CD60-1946-485B-BE68-F1EE10D8ACFE4> ; data: {\n    added = 0;\n    currentUser = 0;\n    groups =     (\n    );\n    photo = nil;\n    profileName = nil;\n    username = nil;\n})}")}, [NSDetailedErrors: (
"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)\" UserInfo={NSValidationErrorKey=profileName, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.), NSValidationErrorObject=<WeGrupp.Users: 0x7fd4d0c3fe60> (entity: Users; id: 0x7fd4d0c13310 <x-coredata:///Users/t9279CD60-1946-485B-BE68-F1EE10D8ACFE4> ; data: {\n    added = 0;\n    currentUser = 0;\n    groups =     (\n    );\n    photo = nil;\n    profileName = nil;\n    username = nil;\n})}",
"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)\" UserInfo={NSValidationErrorKey=username, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.), NSValidationErrorObject=<WeGrupp.Users: 0x7fd4d0c3fe60> (entity: Users; id: 0x7fd4d0c13310 <x-coredata:///Users/t9279CD60-1946-485B-BE68-F1EE10D8ACFE4> ; data: {\n    added = 0;\n    currentUser = 0;\n    groups =     (\n    );\n    photo = nil;\n    profileName = nil;\n    username = nil;\n})}")]
```

If someone finds the solution to my problem I would really appreciate, I really don't know how to fix this!

Comment: Show you managed object context please. And try not to use classic if statement!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I added the managed object context to the code. But what do you mean with not using classic if statements? Do you mean using a switch statement for instance ?

Comment: sorry about if! I meant for-in cycle instead of for.

Answer (score 0):

If you look apple doc you will find like:

> NSValidationMultipleErrorsError                  = 1560,
>   NSValidationMissingMandatoryPropertyError        = 1570,

which can mean that you try to save object with mandatory properties that set to nil.

About errors you can find there:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/ObjectValidation.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Miscellaneous/CoreData_Constants/

Comment: Yes that's the thing, those properties shouldn't be nil. And as you can see in the log I pass non nil values to the mandatory properties, so this is really strange

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution t, pheww...

I have to put in fact the entity and the newUser in the scope of each IF statement and that's it...

Anyway, thanks for your help ;) without your post I wouldn't have pay attention to the place of the entity variable. Thanks again